# Как разобрать XML, полученный от Яндекса?

Tags: php, xmlparser

Как в PHP разобрать такой XML? ([Получено отсюда](https://tech.yandex.ru/fotki/doc/concepts/example-create-album-docpage/))

```
    <app:service xmlns:app="http://www.w3.org/2007/app" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<app:workspace>
    <atom:title>alekna на Яндекс.Фотках</atom:title>
    <app:collection href="http://api-fotki.yandex.ru/api/users/alekna/albums/" id="album-list">
      <atom:title>Все альбомы пользователя alekna</atom:title>
      <app:accept>application/atom+xml; type=entry, application/json; type=entry</app:accept>
    </app:collection>
    <app:collection href="http://api-fotki.yandex.ru/api/users/alekna/photos/" id="photo-list">
      <atom:title>Все фотографии пользователя alekna</atom:title>
      <app:accept>image/*</app:accept>
      <app:categories scheme="http://api-fotki.yandex.ru/api/users/alekna/tags/" />
    </app:collection>
    <app:collection href="http://api-fotki.yandex.ru/api/users/alekna/tags/" id="tag-list">
      <atom:title>Все теги пользователя alekna</atom:title>
      <app:accept />
    </app:collection>
  </app:workspace>
</app:service>
```

Comment: @DmitryOnGamer а как вы предполагаете им обращаться к тегам `atom:title`, `app:collection` и прочим? =)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, сорри не учел что это atom. Тогда самое простое решение формировать запрос к яндексу с указанием ответа в JSON и проблемы нет. https://tech.yandex.ru/fotki/doc/concepts/json-docpage/

Comment: Можно конечно и  через `SimpleXMLElement`, используя неймспейсы  http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.getnamespaces.php  ....... самый простой вариант, как написал DmitryOnGamer - получать ответ как `json` ........ а можно не мучаться с неймспейсами и предавительно через preg_replace  удалить все `app:`, `atom:` и работать как с обычным xml